# jQuery: If current number on pagination is first or last, disable next or previous buttons?

Tags: jquery, pagination

I am building a pagination system from scratch, and would like assistance disabling **'Next/Previous'** switches if the **current** page is either on the **first** or **last** marker (Preference in solution via **jQuery**). Additionally, I require assistance on enabling the switches if the current page has changed:

Previous page

1 (Current)

2

3

4

Next page

I had difficulties in searching this issue, since every one concerning this relates to 'DataTables', which I do not desire at this time.
**HTML:**

```
<div class="row medium-8 large-7 columns beR_blog">
  <div class="beR_blog-page first" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-24" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-5" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-15" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-21" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-4" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="beR_blog-page first" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-24" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-5" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-15" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-21" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-4" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="beR_blog-page first" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-24" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-5" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-15" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-21" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-4" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="beR_blog-page last" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-24" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-5" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-15" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-21" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
    <div id="unique-entry-id-4" class="blog-entry blog-post"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<ul class="pagination text-center" role="navigation" aria-label="Pagination">
  <li class="pagination-previous">
    <a href="#" aria-label="Previous page">Previous <span class="show-for-sr">page</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="test-pagination current" rel="0">1 (Current)</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="test-pagination" rel="1">2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="test-pagination" rel="2">3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="test-pagination" rel="3">4</a>
  </li>
  <li class="pagination-next">
    <a href="#" aria-label="Next page">Next <span class="show-for-sr">page</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.pagination-next a').click(function(){
        if ($('.beR_blog-page:visible').next().length != 0) {
            $('.beR_blog-page:visible').next().show().prev().hide();

        } else {
            $('.beR_blog-page:visible').hide();
            $('.beR_blog-page:first').show();
        }

        if ($('.pagination li a.current').parent().is(':first-child')) {
            $('.pagination li a.current').removeClass('current');
            $('.pagination li:first-child').children().addClass('current');
        } else {
            $('.pagination li a.current').parent().next().children().addClass('current').addClass('new');
            $('.pagination li a.current').removeClass('current');
            $('.pagination li a.new').addClass('current').removeClass('new');
        }
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);

        return false;
    });

    $('.pagination-previous a').click(function(){
        if ($('.beR_blog-page:visible').prev().length != 0) {
            $('.beR_blog-page:visible').prev().show().next().hide();
        } else {
            $('.beR_blog-page:visible').hide();
            $('.beR_blog-page:last').show();
        }

         if ($('.pagination li a.current').parent().is(':last-child')) {
            $('.pagination li a.current').removeClass('current');
            $('.pagination li:last-child').children().addClass('current');
        } else {
            $('.pagination li a.current').parent().prev().children().addClass('current').addClass('new');
            $('.pagination li a.current').removeClass('current');
            $('.pagination li a.new').addClass('current').removeClass('new');
        }
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Do you have a set number of "pages" (e.g. 4)? If not, do you intend to display links to all the "pages" at once or will you only show several at a time? (e.g. "**Previous page 3 4 5 6 7 8 Next page**) Can you also elaborate on the HTML of the  "pages"? Do you load all the "pages" from the start and just hide all but one?

Comment: @IvanModric Yes, I already have the pages ('.beR_blog-page') set up, with five articles in each one. The navigational direction works, and they correctly link to the appropriate pages, so the 'current' will show the given page. The only issue I am struggling with is disabling the Next/Previous buttons when you move the 'current' marker outside the first & last children li elements.

Comment: Then @Chris Jaquez answer should be helpful. Be sure to look at the jsfiddle to understand the functions context.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small demo on how to enable and disable buttons based on an active class present in pagination markup:

https://jsfiddle.net/h3Lcto56/

Basically, this is the important part:

JS

```
function disableButtons() {
  var $pages = $('.page li');
  if($pages.eq(0).hasClass('active')) {
      $('#prev').prop('disabled',true);
      $('#next').prop('disabled',false);
  } else if ($pages.eq($pages.size()-1).hasClass('active')) {
      $('#next').prop('disabled',true);
      $('#prev').prop('disabled',false);
  } else {
      // Make sure buttons get enabled
      $('#prev').prop('disabled',false);
      $('#next').prop('disabled',false);
  }
}
```

"If the element in index 0 is the active one, then we're in the first page, so we can't go back"

"If the element in the last index is the active one, then we're in the last page, so we can't go forward."

"Else, we're in a middle page so we can go either way."